# Logical argument for $(1+2+\dots+n)^2=1^3+2^3+\dots+n^3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, intuition

I know that $1+2+\dots+n=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and $1^3+2^3+\dots+n^3=\dfrac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$ and can show by algebraic calculation. But I am wondering if there is any **logical argument** or any intuitive argument to show that:

> $(1+2+\dots+n)^2=1^3+2^3+\dots+n^3$

Thanks.

Comment: May be help: I made this about two years ago ... $$\\$$ https://pasteboard.co/GLbz0nL.jpg

Comment: May be help: I made this about two years ago ... $$\\$$ https://pasteboard.co/GLbz0nL.jpg